# Command-Key-Up Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to mimic the functionality of the cmd-tab keyboard shortcut where the user can switch between applications hitting a certain key and then when they release command something happens.

I'm using this code right now but it can only detects keydown. I need this to fire on key up

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) {
    NSLog(@"Do my stuff here");
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Informs the receiver that the user has pressed **or released** a modifier
>   key (Shift, Control, and so on).

What you need to do here is when you get the event in which the command key goes down, you need to set a flag somewhere, and in subsequent calls, check for the absence of the command key being down.

For instance, assuming you have an ivar called `_cmdKeyDown`:

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super flagsChanged:theEvent];

    NSUInteger f = [theEvent modifierFlags];
    BOOL isDown = !!(f & NSCommandKeyMask);
    if (isDown != _cmdKeyDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"State changed. Cmd Key is: %@", isDown ? @"Down" : @"Up");
        _cmdKeyDown = isDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify why the questioner's code didn't work: `[event modifierFlags]` doesn't return the modifiers that *changed*; it returns the modifiers *that are now down*. So, if the ⌘ key just went up, then it's no longer down, so its bit in that mask is no longer set—so `[event modifierFlags] & kCommandKeyMask` is `0`.